How to read the next row value is duplicate or not if it is duplicate then start the sequence from 1 based on group
I have complex scenario where i have to start ranking numbers if the next group's record is duplicate then follow the sequence from 1, 2 3 and stop the numbering if new value is available.
Please find below scenario, any help would be appreciated either in R or Spotfire.
in the attached image value 70 is repeated in test id-10,11,12 and 13 so the numbers should be in 1, 2, 3 and 4 but where as 77 is repeated in test id 10 and skipped 11 and started again 12 and 13 for that desired result should be 1,1 and 2

i have tired to using rank baserowid in spotfire but however the second scenario i am unable to get it.

Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for these reasons - and these.

I think the dataset in the image that you shared is not 100% in line with the text explaining what you want to do. For instance, the value 77 is not repeated in the test ID group 13.
However, using dplyr package, I think the following workflow solves your problem.
#create sample data 
data <- data.frame(
  Group = c("52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52","52", "52", "52", "52", "52"),
  Subgroup = c("BD", "BD", "BD", "BD", "BD", "BD","BD", "BD", "BD", "BD", "BD"),
  Test.ID = c(10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14),
  Value = c(70, 65, 77, 70, 73, 91, 77, 70, 70,70, 77)
)

#load package 
library(dplyr)

#add column 

data <- data %>%
  group_by(Value) %>%
  mutate(
    result = if_else(
      c(FALSE, diff(Test.ID) != 1), 1, row_number()
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

Result
   Group Subgroup Test.ID Value result
   <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 52    BD            10    70      1
 2 52    BD            10    65      1
 3 52    BD            10    77      1
 4 52    BD            11    70      2
 5 52    BD            11    73      1
 6 52    BD            11    91      1
 7 52    BD            12    77      1
 8 52    BD            12    70      3
 9 52    BD            13    70      4
10 52    BD            13    70      1
11 52    BD            14    77      1

Hope this helps!

Data from Flap's answer,
Here is a base R solution with ave.
My first attempt was to group by Group, Subgroup, Value and apply seq_along to get consecutive numbers but there is a problem when Test.ID equals 13, there are two Value's 70 and the numbers also become consecutive, 4 and 5, instead of two 4's. See rows 9 and 10 below.
data <- data.frame(
  Group = c("52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52","52", "52", "52", "52", "52"),
  Subgroup = c("BD", "BD", "BD", "BD", "BD", "BD","BD", "BD", "BD", "BD", "BD"),
  Test.ID = c(10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14),
  Value = c(70, 65, 77, 70, 73, 91, 77, 70, 70,70, 77)
)

cbind(
  data,
  result = with(data, ave(Value, Group, Subgroup, Value, FUN = seq_along))
)
#>    Group Subgroup Test.ID Value result
#> 1     52       BD      10    70      1
#> 2     52       BD      10    65      1
#> 3     52       BD      10    77      1
#> 4     52       BD      11    70      2
#> 5     52       BD      11    73      1
#> 6     52       BD      11    91      1
#> 7     52       BD      12    77      2
#> 8     52       BD      12    70      3
#> 9     52       BD      13    70      4
#> 10    52       BD      13    70      5
#> 11    52       BD      14    77      3

Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.1.0
So first create a temporary data set with unique rows, then apply the logic above, then merge with the original data set.
udata <- data |> unique()
udata$result <- udata |>
  with(ave(Value, Group, Subgroup, Value, FUN = seq_along))
data <- merge(data, udata)
data
#>    Group Subgroup Test.ID Value result
#> 1     52       BD      10    65      1
#> 2     52       BD      10    70      1
#> 3     52       BD      10    77      1
#> 4     52       BD      11    70      2
#> 5     52       BD      11    73      1
#> 6     52       BD      11    91      1
#> 7     52       BD      12    70      3
#> 8     52       BD      12    77      2
#> 9     52       BD      13    70      4
#> 10    52       BD      13    70      4
#> 11    52       BD      14    77      3

# final clean up
rm(udata)

Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.1.0
